# Python - AF_BLUETOOTH

Tags: python, networking, bluetooth, communication

Is there currently any documentation for AF_BLUETOOTH in python? Every time I try to find any, the only think I run into is a blog discussing remote controlled cars. There are virtually no examples I can find on Google and the py wiki doesn't go into detail on how to use it either.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be several small blog entries on this topic but not a complete bluetooth library for it. I've scratched together my own based on this information: http://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/ and capturing the output of hcitool for the functions which seem to be missing. For example, using this function:

```
import subprocess

def scan():
    a = subprocess.Popen(["hcitool", "scan"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()[2:]
    if a == []:
        return "ERROR"
    else:
        return a
```

Allows you to scan for nearby bluetooth devices and deposits them into a list of [DeviceMac, DeviceName, DeviceMac, DeviceName] format. I will be updating this and distributing it with a P2P bluetooth communications program I've deving soon.